# Перебор всех возможных вариантов на основании ответов

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, графы, комбинаторика, перебор

Нужно посчитать общее количество комбинаций и посторить все возможные последовательности ответов на основании массива вопросов и ответов к ниму.
по сути вывести все возможные варианты вопрос->ответ на основании выбора.
какой алгоритм для этого подойдет лучше всего ?

```
    [
   {
      "id":"x1",
      "question":"question 1 ?",
      "answers":[
         {
            "value":"yes",
            "nextId":"x2"
         },
         {
            "value":"no",
            "nextId":"x3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"x2",
      "question":"question 2 ?",
      "answers":[
         {
            "value":"yes",
            "nextId":"x4"
         },
         {
            "value":"no",
            "nextId":"x5"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"x3",
      "question":"question 3 ?",
      "answers":[
         {
            "value":"yes",
            "nextId":"x4"
         },
         {
            "value":"no",
            "nextId":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"x4",
      "question":"question 4 ?",
      "answers":[
         {
            "value":"yes",
            "nextId":null
         },
         {
            "value":"no",
            "nextId":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"x5",
      "question":"question 5 ?",
      "answers":[
         {
            "value":"yes",
            "nextId":null
         },
         {
            "value":"no",
            "nextId":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Если на каждый из n вопросов два ответа, то общее количество комбинаций 2^n?, логично же?

Comment: Соответственно перебор можно осуществить, проходя в цикле числа от нуля до указанного предела, и для выбора соответствующего варианта использовать k-й бит числа (счётчика цикла) для ответа на k-й вопрос  (0 или 1)

Comment: у вас тут направленный граф и найти надо все пути из заданной вершины. Можете рекурсией пройтись.

Answer (score 1):

Дан массив из одинаковых JSON'ов. В каждом из них есть строка с вопросом и массив ответов. Нужно будет два цикла: первый будет проходиться по массиву вопросов, второй (вложенный) для каждого вопроса будет проходиться по массиву ответов. Получается обычный проход по массиву, со вложенным циклом:

```
для каждого json в массиве:
    для каждого ответа в json:
        json.вопрос + ответ
```

Сложность примерно O(n*m) где `n - кол-во вопросов`, `m - среднее кол-во ответов на один вопрос`

Comment: Это перечисление ответов, а не генерация всех комбинаций ответов

Comment: Тогда что вы хотите получить на выходе? Число комбинаций? Ассоциативный массив "вопрос" => "ответ"?

Comment: Автор хочет получить все возможные комбинации ответов. Например, для трех вопросов это будет 8 вариантов `нет нет нет, нет нет да, ... да да да` (000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111)